# Where/how do I reduce travel on my brake levers?

Tags: brakes, brake-levers

How do I reduce travel my brake lever? (To brake currently, I practically have to depress it all the way to the handle bar.)

I don't see any place to put an allen wrench anywhere. What am I missing?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have these always been like this, or were they good previously?

Comment: Tighten the cables -- that twisty thing on the front of the levers.

Comment: @whatsisname no they've kinda gradually gone out of whack

Comment: @DanielRHicks If anything it seemed like unscrewing the adjuster made them tighter, though not by enough to fix the problem. What else can I try?

Comment: Do you know how to use the adjuster?  Loosen the lock nut then unscrew the adjuster nut to make the cable tighter.  If you run out of range then you need to loosen the cable clamp on the brake and pull the cable tighter (then tighten the clamp again).

Comment: Thank you @DanielRHicks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The brake levers are adjustable.
[image]

0. The locking nut (nr 1) has/should have been tightened to keep the adjustment mechanism from re-adjusting by itself
1. Loosen nut nr 1 (if possible) to loosen adjustement screw
2. Turn adjustment screw nr 2 so it comes out of the brake lever to tighten the cable so that the wheel spins freely when brake lever is not pressed
3. Tighten nut nr 1 to secure the adjustment screw
4. Verify brake function in safe environment before use in traffic

If this isn't enough, the brake cable needs adjustment/refitting at the brake pad end. If you are unsure about how, I'd recommend visiting the local bikeshop to get their help or ask for information as incorrect installation of the cable might cause the brakes to stop working completely.

Comment: *4. Verify brake function in safe environment before use in traffic* and when doing unfamiliar or complex brake jobs, fix one without touching the other, verify the first, then fix the other (some brakes can be left utterly useless by a small omission).

Comment: "clockwise" is somewhat ambiguous here. You might start with "*0. The two nuts have been tightened against each other to hold them in place.*", and then say "loosen" or "tighten" rather than specifying (counter-)clockwise.

Comment: @RayButterworth - Good catch, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: It’s also a good idea to check that the brake pads are not rubbing after using the barrel adjuster. Lift the bike off the ground and check that the wheels spin freely.

Comment: @Michael - I mentioned that at the end of step 2

Answer (score 5):

As you say they gradually went out of whack, then the culprit is almost certainly  the brake pads wearing down. This is normal.  As MagnusK has suggested in his answer the cable can be easily adjusted using the barrel adjuster, but if this is all you do, its probably doing it wrong.

With most mechanical brakes, the cable adjustment only affects the outer brake pad, The inner brake pads also needs adjustment. If the braking is affected to the extent you have shown in you photos, the inner definitely needs attention.  If you only adjust the cable, and not the inner pad, the brakes have to push the disc and clearance has to be increased, decreasing braking performance.

Have a look at Park Tools web site for exactly how to adjust mechanical brake pads [Here](https://www.parktool.com/en-int/blog/repair-help/mechanical-disc-brake-alignment).

Answer (score -2):

One of the easiest ways to reduce travel on your brake levers is to adjust your drop handle. This can be done by loosening it and then moving it up or down according to how much adjustment you need. Additionally, make sure that your pads are in good condition and that they're correctly seated against the disc brakes. By doing these two simple things, you will be able to reduce travel on your brake levers without having to resorting to changing cables or rotors!

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I don't understand what you're trying to suggest; what I'm reading is that you're suggesting moving the lever on the bar, but that doesn't make sense.  Can you please make sure you're using standard terminology (what is a "drop handle?") and add some photos to indicate what you're suggesting.

Comment: I think (partly @DavidW) this refers to drop bars and the brake levers fitted to them - but as the photos are clearly of flat bars that's not much help.  Also the answer appears to address to question title without noticing that the issue isn't the rest position and hand size but the need for correct adjustment due to pad wear.

Comment: @ChrisH I thought "drop handle" might mean drop bars, but that didn't make sense in the context of the question, which as you note are clearly not drops...  Hence my request for some diagrams about what this answer is trying to suggest.